# Slow MySQL replace / complex query

Tags: mysql, performance, mysqlimport

I am working on a MySQL query that needs to go through 1+ million rows in table A and 5+ million in table B. The query selects all unique people from table A and inner joins with the sales for each person on table B. Index is set on both tables where necessary.

The goal here is to add all unique Email addresses from table A with data from table B into table C.

I am looking for the most optimized way to do this. Included is the select part of a REPLACE INTO query being used that will pull records in the specified id's. It is a simple CASE statement with an IN condition.

I also have the exact same query using NOT IN vs IN for the sub query. That one times out.

Looking forward to any help anyone can provide and hopefully a more optimal way of doing this.

```
SELECT
    c.Email,
    MAX(c.Birthdate)
    UPPER(c.Deleted) AS Deleted,
    UPPER(c.Inactive) AS Inactive,
    UPPER(c.SendEmail) AS SendEmail,
    CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Site SEPARATOR ']['),']') AS SITEID,
    CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Studio SEPARATOR ']['),']') AS STUDIO,
    (   SELECT CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s2.Service SEPARATOR ']['),']')
        FROM my_example c2
        INNER JOIN my_example_sales s2 ON s2.idMember = c2.idMember AND s2.Site = c2.Site WHERE c2.Email = c.Email
    ) as SERVICES,
    (   SELECT MAX(date(s1.Date)) as Date
        FROM my_example_sales s1
        WHERE s1.idMember = c.idMember 
AND s1.Site = c.Site
        AND (CASE WHEN s1.Site = '1' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('1','6','7','12','18','22')
        WHEN s1.Site = '2' THEN s1.ProductID = '156'
        WHEN s1.Site = '3' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('3','5','6')
        WHEN s1.Site = '4' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('11','15')
        WHEN s1.Site = '5' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
        WHEN s1.Site = '6' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
        WHEN s1.Site = '7' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
    WHEN s1.Site = '8' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
    WHEN s1.Site = '9' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
    WHEN s1.Site = '10' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('7','11','17','30','31')
    WHEN s1.Site = '11' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
    WHEN s1.Site = '12' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('7','11','17','30','31')
        WHEN s1.Site = '13' THEN s1.ProductID = '23' END)
        WHERE 1
        ORDER BY s1.Date DESC
        LIMIT 0,1
    ) as lastPurchaseFreeWeek,
    NOW() as dateModified
FROM my_example c
WHERE c.Email !=''
GROUP BY c.Email
ORDER BY c.ModDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving your subselects to joins should yield some performance increase:

```
SELECT
    c.Email,
    MAX(c.Birthdate)
    UPPER(c.Deleted) AS Deleted,
    UPPER(c.Inactive) AS Inactive,
    UPPER(c.SendEmail) AS SendEmail,
    CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Site SEPARATOR ']['),']') AS SITEID,
    CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Studio SEPARATOR ']['),']') AS STUDIO,
    c2.SERVICES,
    s1.`Date` as lastPurchaseFreeWeek,
    NOW() as dateModified
FROM my_example c
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s2.Service SEPARATOR ']['),']') AS SERVICES
        FROM my_example c2
        INNER JOIN my_example_sales s2 ON s2.idMember = c2.idMember AND s2.Site = c2.Site
    ) c2 ON c2.Email = c.Email
INNER JOIN (   
        SELECT MAX(date(s1.Date)) as `Date`
        FROM my_example_sales s1
        WHERE (CASE WHEN s1.Site = '1' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('1','6','7','12','18','22')
                WHEN s1.Site = '2' THEN s1.ProductID = '156'
                WHEN s1.Site = '3' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('3','5','6')
                WHEN s1.Site = '4' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('11','15')
                WHEN s1.Site = '5' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
                WHEN s1.Site = '6' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
                WHEN s1.Site = '7' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
                WHEN s1.Site = '8' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
                WHEN s1.Site = '9' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
                WHEN s1.Site = '10' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('7','11','17','30','31')
                WHEN s1.Site = '11' THEN s1.ProductID = '23'
                WHEN s1.Site = '12' THEN s1.ProductID IN ('7','11','17','30','31')
                WHEN s1.Site = '13' THEN s1.ProductID = '23' END)
    ) s1 ON ( s1.idMember = c.idMember AND s1.Site = c.Site )
WHERE c.Email !=''
GROUP BY c.Email
ORDER BY c.ModDate DESC
```

Comment: Great suggestion! Applying your changes shaved 30 seconds off the query time, but the result is empty. I also had to add s1.idMember, s1.Site, c.Email fields to the inner join select as MySQL complained about them not existing. The result set can be expected to be ~640K records.